# Alternative way to create a GUI in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

How can I create a GUI in Matlab?

I know about GUIDE, but I am not satisfied with the amount of customization that it provides.
What other options I have ?

Comment: What is it exactly in GUIDE that bothers you?

Comment: You can always program the GUI yourself. Just create the widgets and place them around..

Comment: @Andrey : very less options for customization in GUIDE to make it better is what bothers me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a big proponent of using the Matlab-Java interface for GUI's in Matlab.  It's a little more cumbersome, but definitely worth the trouble if it's a reasonably featured GUI.  It's just like programming in Java, but using the m-script interface.  To create a Java GUI you'll need to use the Matlab built-in function `javaObjectEDT` and pass it the class from which you want an instantiation.

```
frame = javaObjectEDT('javax.swing.JFrame');
```

The `javaObjectEDT` call is recommended by the Mathworks to ensure garbage collection, etc.
When you set a callback to a Matlab function handle, you'll need to follow:

```
hjObj = handle(jObj, 'CallbackProperties');
set(hjObj,'MouseClickedCallback',{@treeClicked,fig},'ToolTipText','Tip: use Alt-Click to edit plotting functions');
```

Which is explained [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/294487).

There are a lot of details, but down at the core it's m-script based Java that integrates really well with Matlab.